# In Intellij, what is the name of the keyboard shortcut that can switch from one tab group to another?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Here's the scenario:  I have "split vertically" so I have two tab groups, one on the left, one on the right.  My cursor is in the left tab group and I'd like to switch it to the right group.  Right now the way I do this is by moving my mouse to the right group and clicking somewhere.  Is there a keyboard shortcut to do this?

I'd like to know the name of this shortcut so I can find it in the "keymappings".

Comment: I don't agree with this close suggestion.  It says, "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.** You may be able to get help on Super User."  This is definitely about a tool used primarily for programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the action is "Goto Next Splitter".